# How to pass 'allowscriptaccess' parameter to flowplayer

Tags: jquery, flowplayer

We are using flowplayer for running a video. I have to set `allowscriptaccess` to `'samedomain'`. Is it correct to set it like this:

```
flowplayer("player", "/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",  {
  clip: {
    onStart: function() {
      msgs.innerHTML += "Common Clip event listener called<br>";
    },
  },
  allowscriptaccess: 'samedomain'
});
```

Comment: Bit of formatting and language changes. Removed the sign off.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
flowplayer("player", {
        src: "/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",
        allowscriptaccess: 'samedomain'
    }
```